# How to change UITabViewController index after popping to root view controller in iOS Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, rootviewcontroller

I have UITabbarController as root view controller. I need to pop to root view controller and change the selected index of the tab bar.

I am using this code, it popus to tabbar but selected index is not changed

```
   self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)

    if let tab = self.tabBarController {
           tab.selectedIndex = 0      
    }
```

I have used this as an alternative as well, but still not success

```
    self.navigationController?.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

The view controller can't change the index after popping to root controller because the controller doesn't exist at this point of time.

You can change the index then pop up to the root controller.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using below code:

```
guard let vc = self.navigationController?.viewControllers else { return }

for controller in vc {
   if controller.isKind(of: CustomTabBarViewController.self) {
      let tabVC = controller as! CustomTabBarViewController
      tabVC.selectedIndex = 0
      self.navigationController?.popToViewController(tabVC, animated: true)
   }
}
```